# iOS app won't run until device reboot after ad hoc install

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4

Every time I install my app to an iDevice using the ad hoc distribution method (e.g. archive, create an .ipa file and let my testers download it), the app will not run until the device is rebooted. Much like the second link posted below, I did not have this problem before upgrading to iOS 5 and XCode 4.3.1 -- currently running iOS 5.1 / XCode 4.3.2 and still having the same problem. If I connect the iPhone / iPad using USB (and run directly from xcode), the app installs normally and runs fine.

Currently, when installing ad hoc, one of two things happens:

1: The app installs "normally" and the icon is visible -- but pressing it brings up the launch image, then the app fails to black screen -- then back to springboard. App never gets any further.

• or •

2: App installation seems to proceed normally, then when the "Installing..." phase is complete, the app icon simply vanishes. Reboot the iPhone and the app icon is exactly where it is supposed to be.

In either case, after a reboot of the iPhone it runs fine.

Any suggestions??

This is the closest issue I could find, but I have this problem on iOS 5.0 / 5.1 and even when installing my app to devices for the first time:
[iPhone app fails to launch after install on iOS 4, works after device reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123729/iphone-app-fails-to-launch-after-install-on-ios-4-works-after-device-reboot)

I also found this article, so I checked my Entitlements setting (in Targets) -- Not enabled: [ad hoc app failed to install on real iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851441/ad-hoc-app-failed-to-install-on-real-ipad)

Comment: Hmmm... No one else has encountered this??

Answer (score 1):

I've had this exact problem before when I have a different 'Bundle Identifier' set in the Info.plist to the App Id you set up in the provisioning portal.

If that doesn't work, you might try checking the log of your device when attempting to install the ad hoc ipa.

XCode -> Window -> Organizer -> Devices -> Your device -> Console